# How do I avoid the resources.pri error when creating the package for the PSI HoloLensCaptureApp via Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, hololens

Microsoft has a framework for multimodal AI called [Platform for Situated Intelligence (PSI)](https://github.com/microsoft/psi). In the latest release, they introduced a tool called [HoloLensCapture](https://github.com/microsoft/psi/tree/master/Sources/MixedReality/HoloLensCapture), which allows for capturing all the data provided by the HoloLens and streaming it to a computer. However, you need to create the app package yourself in Visual Studio for the [capture app](https://github.com/microsoft/psi/tree/master/Sources/MixedReality/HoloLensCapture/HoloLensCaptureApp). The instructions provided (after you fix the initial bugs due to the graphical assets), result in the following error:

[image: Package generation error]

There is in fact a resource in the package manifest of the capture app.

How do I get the package to be correctly generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix to this issue is as follows: in the package creation wizard, on the "select and configure packages" stage, change the "generate app bundle" option from "Always" to "If needed" or "Never".

This should solve the issue. Note however that this also means that you must specify the three dependencies manually as framework packages when uploading the app package to the HoloLens via the device portal.